# Postgres App: Configuring settings

Tags: postgresql, postgresapp

I cannot seem to change the command being called when I open psql through the Postgres app.  I can successfully open a connection by calling:

```
postgres --config-file=/usr/local/var/postgres/postgresql.conf -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

but when I select "Open psql" in the app, I see:

```
psql: FATAL:  database "incorrect_database_name" does not exist
```

How can I configure this?

Comment: What do you mean by "postgres app"? Can you show the psql command you are using to make the connection?

Comment: I'm referring to the Postgres App: https://postgresapp.com/documentation/configuration-general.html.  I usually use it to start the connection when my Mac boots so that I can ru n my local app and there is a connection available